# In GTK, return focus to text input after opening new shell

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, gtk, swt

The following small example behaves differently on Windows and on Ubuntu:

- `mainShell` is a `Shell` that contains a `Text` input and  a `Button`
- when the button is pressed, another shell `smallShell` is `open`ed (with a specfic style)
- after the shell is opened, the focus should go back to the text input

On windows, the focus indeed goes back to the text input. On Ubuntu, however, the `smallShell` remains focussed, even though we call `setActive` or `setFocus`. I want it to behave like in the first case and yield the focus.

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ShellWithoutTitleBar {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    
    final Shell mainShell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    mainShell.setSize(300, 200);
    mainShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    
    final Shell smallShell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
    smallShell.setSize(150, 150);
    
    Text text = new Text(mainShell, SWT.BORDER);
    
    Button button = new Button(mainShell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("foo");
    mainShell.open();
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            smallShell.open();
            mainShell.setActive();
            text.setFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) { }
    });

    // Set up the event loop.
    while (!smallShell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        // If no more entries in event queue
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

}
```

Everything works fine when I omit the `SWT.ON_TOP` flag, however it is critical for my use case that the new shell is always-on-top.

I have tried random ways to forcibly give the focus back to the text input or at least the main shell but nothing seems to have any effect.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. The key idea is to

1. use `setVisible` instead of open for the child shell --- In fact, `open` explicitly sets the focus to the child shell ([see documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-06/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html#open())).
2. Listen for SWT.Activate and return the focus to the text field --- This does not work e.g. with FocusListener.

Here's a modified version that has this issue fixed.

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class ShellWithoutTitleBar2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    
    final Shell mainShell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    mainShell.setSize(300, 200);
    mainShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    mainShell.open();
    
    final Shell overlayShell = new Shell(display, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.ON_TOP);
    overlayShell.setSize(150, 150);
    overlayShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    
    Text text = new Text(mainShell, SWT.BORDER);
    
    Button button = new Button(mainShell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("open overlayShell");
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) { } 
        @Override public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
            // this is the one key part of the answer. we use `setVisible` instead of `open`.
            overlayShell.setVisible(true);
        }
        @Override public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) { }
    });
    
    // this is the other key part of the asnwer. we listen for `SWT.Activate` instead of focus or sth else.
      overlayShell.addListener(SWT.Activate, (e)-> {
          text.setFocus();
      });
      
    // Set up the event loop.
    while (!mainShell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        // If no more entries in event queue
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }

}
```