# In GTK, SWT.ON_TOP causes unpredictable behaviour on .setfocus()

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, gtk, swt

Here's what I want to achieve:

1. On some trigger (here: click of a button), a floating toolbar should appear. The focus should still be on the text input field after this.
2. When a button in the floating toolbar is clicked, the focus should remain with the text input field.

The floating toolbar should realised by a `Shell` that is always-on-top.

I have achieved (1) by introducing a `ShellListener` on the overlay shell that calls `text.setFocus` (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63019974/in-gtk-return-focus-to-text-input-after-opening-new-shell)).

I have achieved (2) by keeping a `MouseListener` on the button and calling `text.setFocus` on click.

Now, my problem is that each solution works fine on its own. However, when I use both listeners (as in the MWE below), I get weird behaviour:

- The text field is correctly focussed after the overlay shell appears
- Clicking the button in the overlay shell does not return the focus to the text field unless

  - You manually focus the main shell by clicking anywhere in it
  - You spam clicks on the button in the overlay shell, after some random amount of clicks, the text input is correctly focussed, and then also for each successive click.

This seems to a problem specific to Ubuntu (GTK). I am using SWT 4.16.

Consider the following MWE.

Note that everything works fine if we omit `SWT.ON_TOP` and replace it with `SWT.SHELL_TRIM`.

Weirdly enough, with SWT.ON_TOP,  `shellActivated` on `overlayShell` does not always trigger when the button in the overlay shell is clicked, and when it does, it does not coincide with the focus being correctly transferred.

```java
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.FocusListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ShellListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class ShellWithoutTitleBarSO2 {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    
    final Shell mainShell = new Shell(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    mainShell.setSize(300, 200);
    mainShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    mainShell.open();
    
    Text text = new Text(mainShell, SWT.BORDER);

    final Shell overlayShell = new Shell(display, SWT.ON_TOP);
    overlayShell.setSize(150, 150);
    overlayShell.setLocation(400, 200);
    overlayShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    
    // (1) give back focus when overlay shell is first opened
    overlayShell.addShellListener(new ShellListener() {
        @Override public void shellActivated(ShellEvent arg0) {
            text.setFocus();
        }
        @Override public void shellClosed(ShellEvent arg0) { }
        @Override public void shellDeactivated(ShellEvent arg0) { }
        @Override public void shellDeiconified(ShellEvent arg0) { } 
        @Override public void shellIconified(ShellEvent arg0) { }
    });
    
    Button button = new Button(mainShell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("open overlayShell");
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) { } 
        @Override public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) { }
        @Override public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e) { 
            overlayShell.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    
    Button buttonInOverlay = new Button(overlayShell, SWT.PUSH | SWT.BORDER);
    buttonInOverlay.setText("foo");
    
    // (2) give back focus when button in overlay is clicked
    // this seems to only work (randomly, race-condition like) when overlay shell
    // has SWT.ON_TOP. If not, then no effect.
    buttonInOverlay.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) { }
        @Override public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) { }
        @Override public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) { 
            boolean didSetFocus = text.setFocus();
            // notably, this is true even when focus is effectively not set
        }
    });
    
    // Set up the event loop.
    while (!mainShell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
        // If no more entries in event queue
        display.sleep();
      }
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

I've begun stepping through the SWT source code but I'm quite puzzled by it. Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this weird issue?